# CDs will automatically mount, but not DVDs

Tags: linux, automounting, dvd

I need for all devices to be automatically mounted. These discs contain some data files (these are RW discs, for the record). They are successfully mounted and accessed using the same drive on a Windows 10 machine, so this can't be a hardware issue.

CD was successfully mounted as UDF Volume and files could be accessed. DVD containing the same data was not mounted. In one particular case it did show up as UDF Volume (after DVD was inserted and then removed), but since then I was not able to reproduce that state. It simply didn't show up.

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# Entry for /dev/sda6 :

UUID=e2b8e04f-4c72-4793-ae76-8e3f1f699c7b / ext4 relatime,acl 1 1 none /proc proc defaults 0 0

# Entry for /dev/sda5 :

UUID=228d5438-38f9-4682-b2da-9348a48871a9 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Couldn't use dpkg (I use Mageia by the way), but here's output of `lsblk -f` when cd is inserted:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID MOUNTPOINT
sda
├─sda1
├─sda2
├─sda3
├─sda5                   [SWAP]
└─sda6                   /
sr0                      /media/cd`
```

Comment: `cat /etc/fstab` and `dpkg -l libblkid`

Comment: Edited the question due to formatting problems.

Comment: What desktop environment?

Comment: It's running Openbox

Comment: Current linux-Distros mount under /media/$USER . Any auto-mount Programms installt? Like pmount? `rpm -qa | grep -i mount`

Comment: Thunar (thunar-volman), however there is nothing particular in its settings about CDs/DVDs (only options for automatically playing media content, but I've got data disks).

Comment: `rpm -qa` only showed libmount1. Also dvds can be manually mounted, but they don't show up under `/dev/disk` lists (I've got a piece of software that uses those).

Comment: @Bahamut Another thing, I have tried using /etc/fstab configuration: `/dev/dvdrw /media/dvdrw udf,iso9660 auto,exec,user,utf8 0 0` It worked on CD (mounting it to /media/dvdrw as opposed to usual automount location), however DVD was only mounted at the startup, not when inserted. Additionally, there was no folder corresponding to the DVD in the `/dev/disk` folder.

Comment: What Version of libmount1 ?

Comment: @Bahamut libmount1-2.24-2